# Issues creating PDF using wicked and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rails-api, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to create a downloadable PDF using wicked and Rails API. At the moment I can only get a PDF to download but the contents are empty and the file name is response.pdf.pdf.

This is the method I'm using to generate the PDF when a GET request is made to a specific score.

```
def download_pdf(score)
    html = render_to_string(:action => :show, :layout => "pdf.html.erb", :template => "scores/show.pdf.erb", locals:{:score => score}) 
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html) 

    send_data(pdf,  
      :filename => 'test.pdf',
      :disposition => 'attachment')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today. Quite late but will be useful for people looking for a solution to this.

You will have to inherit from ActionController::Base and not ActionController::API. Or you can override render_to_string with the following code.

```
def render_to_string(*args)
  controller = ActionController::Base.new
  controller.locale = I18n.locale
  controller.render_to_string(*args)
end
```

reference: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/652